# Do a CouchDB reduce query for a single key

Tags: couchdb

I have a CouchDB with following doc:

```js
{
  "name":"Chris",
  "tags":["mustache", "music", "couchdb"]
}

{
  "name":"Noah",
  "tags":["hypertext", "philosophy", "couchdb"]
}

{
  "name":"Jan",
  "tags":["drums", "bike", "couchdb"]
}
```

Map Function:

```js
function(dude) {
  if(dude.name && dude.tags) {
    dude.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      emit(tag, 1);
    });
  }
}
```

Reduce Function:

```js
function(keys, values) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

Now, if I query the view with the `?group=true` parameter, I get back the count for each tag:

```js
{"rows":[
{"key":"bike","value":1},
{"key":"couchdb","value":3},
{"key":"drums","value":1},
{"key":"hypertext","value":1},
{"key":"music","value":1},
{"key":"mustache","value":1},
{"key":"philosophy","value":1}
]}
```

What query should I use to get the value of just *"couchdb"* alone?

This example was taken from the CouchDB book, while my live application has 1000s of keys and most of the time I just needs to find the count of one individual key.

I am not able to use *key=* parameter, which is really what I want, as it returns an empty result.

If I query `?group=true&startkey="couchdb"&endkey="drums"` I get the count of *couchdb* alone, but I cannot use *startkey=* and *endkey=* because I do not know what the next key will be in a live DB.

What solutions would you recommend in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key="couchdb"&group=true` should work.

We have several views and queries in production that work exactly like that, and I just tried one of them. If you get an empty result, maybe the key is not exactly the same that you emit. Double check if you emit a single string as the key (your posted map function does that right) and if there are any capitalization differences (use `toLowerCase()` to be sure - which should not be necessary in your example).

In other situations (any tag starting with *"couchdb"*) you could use an *endkey* with a high character at the end (*"couchdb\ufff0"*), but this doesn't help here.

Comment: I agree that the simple key and group query should just work. One thing to watch out for might be correctly urlEncoding any double-quotes that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Bernhard. I needed to properly escape a space in key.